# How to create extend a jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins, extend

I'm trying to create a jquery plugin

initially the plugin is used like

```
$('element').plugin;
```

Now, i want to extend it further to call specific operations like

```
$('element').plugin.create;
```

or

```
$('element').plugin.delete;
```

any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Read through [this](http://jupiterit.com/#news/writing-the-perfect-jquery-plugin) great tutorial on plugin creation from Justin Meyer

Answer (score 0):

That seems like you want to create a widget. Look here for a good explanation of what widgets do as opposed to plugins: http://bililite.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/ Typically, you would then call your plugin's methods like this: `$('element').plugin('create')`